# Code completion key bindings in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

When doing a <kbd>M-x describe-mode</kbd> in a .el file, I noticed that the Emacs-Lisp mode actually does code completion.  However, `lisp-complete-symbol` is bound to <kbd>M-TAB</kbd>.  In Windows, this key binding is taken by Windows for switching the active window.  Most IDE's use <kbd>C-SPC</kbd>, but that's taken in Emacs as well.  What is a good, fairly common key binding for code completion?

Comment: Of course, you can type `ESC TAB`.

Comment: +1 You're right.  Why does that work?  ESC=Meta?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you like completion of all kinds, I recommend <kbd>M-/</kbd> and binding that to [hippie-expand](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HippieExpand).

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-/") 'hippie-expand)
```

It does a variety of completions, which are controlled by the variable `hippie-expand-try-functions-list`.  In the .el files, you can set that to do the `'try-complete-lisp-symbol` first to get the behavior you're asking for above, along with all the other expansions hippie-expand provides.

This would do that for you:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'move-lisp-completion-to-front)
(defun move-lisp-completion-to-front ()
  "Adjust hippie-expand-try-functions-list to have lisp completion at the front."
  (make-local-variable 'hippie-expand-try-functions-list)
  (setq hippie-expand-try-functions-list 
        (cons 'try-complete-lisp-symbol
              (delq 'try-complete-lisp-symbol hippie-expand-try-functions-list)))
  (setq hippie-expand-try-functions-list 
        (cons 'try-complete-lisp-symbol-partially
              (delq 'try-complete-lisp-symbol-partially hippie-expand-try-functions-list))))
```

Comment: Hippie-expand sounds interesting.  Why did you choose M-/ instead of M-SPC (as shown in the EmacsWiki page)?  Also how do you make that cool box around the M-/?

Comment: @User1 `M-/` is the default binding for `dabbrev` (for which hippe-expand is a replacement).  Also `M-SPC` is by default bound to `'just-one-space` which I use all the time.  And lastly, the cool box is made by using the tag <kbd>KEY</kbd>

Comment: BTW, you can apply delq to the result of delq and save yourself some cut-n-paste: `(cons 'a (cons 'b (delq 'a (delq 'b list))))`

Comment: `M-/` is also the binding recommended by [GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/autotype/Hippie-Expand.html): Typically you would bind hippie-expand to `M-/` with `dabbrev-expand`, the standard binding of `M-/`, providing one of the expansion possibilities.

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>C-M-i</kbd>; no customization required.

Answer (score 7):

As Trey Jackson mentioned, `hippie-expand` is the way to go, but along with binding it to <kbd>M-/</kbd>, I also like having the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key do all my completion work for me. So I have this from the [Emacs-Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TabCompletion) in my .emacs file:

```
;;function to implement a smarter TAB (EmacsWiki)
(defun smart-tab ()
  "This smart tab is minibuffer compliant: it acts as usual in
    the minibuffer. Else, if mark is active, indents region. Else if
    point is at the end of a symbol, expands it. Else indents the
    current line."
  (interactive)
  (if (minibufferp)
      (unless (minibuffer-complete)
        (hippie-expand nil))
    (if mark-active
        (indent-region (region-beginning)
                       (region-end))
      (if (looking-at "\\_>")
         (hippie-expand nil)
        (indent-for-tab-command)))))
(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'smart-tab)
```

You could have hippie expand settings as follows:

```
;;settings for hippie-expand
(setq hippie-expand-try-functions-list
       '(try-complete-lisp-symbol
         try-complete-lisp-symbol-partially
         try-expand-dabbrev
         try-expand-dabbrev-from-kill
         try-expand-dabbrev-all-buffers
         try-expand-line
         try-complete-file-name-partially
         try-complete-file-name))
```

Answer (score 2):

I use:

```
(define-key function-key-map [(control tab)] [?\M-\t])
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `M-.` and `M-/` for the 2 completion modes - hippie-expand and the standard emacs one.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your `.emacs` to make Windows give Emacs the use of `M-TAB`:

```
(when (fboundp 'w32-register-hot-key) (w32-register-hot-key [M-tab]))
```